# How to get log when service in android is killed

Tags: android

I have an android application which has got a service running in background, I was wanted to test the Doze mode in latest MARSHMALLOW release, for which I want to log if my service is killed, how can I do that?

I believe if service is killed, I can't even log that part because the whole application is then killed. Can someone guide, HOW CAN I GET THE LOG WHEN MY SERVICE IS KILLED?

Trying it in `onDestroy` would not make sense I believe.

Thanks

Comment: `onStop()` is better to log

Comment: @MD services don't have onStop, do they?

Comment: But once it reaches ``onStop``, i won't be able to send that log into Database where i am actually logging, it will kill the application itself by that time. Note : Logging means i want to log in DB and not just SYSTEM.OUT.PRINT, as i will be monitoring DOZE mode for quiet a long time (may be even more than 7 hours), so i want to log in such a way where user interaction is not required